# How to animate circle along path

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have an animation in which a circle follows the sides of a square:
[image]

Now I would like to make the circle follow the sides of a polygon. Can anyone help me please?

Code

```
namespace polygon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x, y;
        Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 5);
        PointF[] puncte = new PointF[4];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
            
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            puncte[0] = new PointF(100, 100);
            puncte[1] = new PointF(320, 100);
            puncte[2] = new PointF(380, 320);
            puncte[3] = new PointF(100, 320);
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(p1, puncte);

            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x, y, 40, 40);
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (x < 300 && y == 80)
                x = x + 20;
            else
              if (y < 300 && x == 300)
                y = y + 20;
            else
          if (y == 300 && x > 80)
                x = x - 20;
            else
                y = y - 20;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a function that takes two points and two ints, one for the number of points on that line and one for the index of the one you want  and returns a Point. It should calculate the float slope and the float deltaX and deltaY and then can calculate the nth point.

Comment: @TaW I tried, but I can't. Maybe I don't know how to declare the syntax well. Do you think you can show me how in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace _2_amaliy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x, y;
        Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 5);
        PointF[] puncte = new PointF[4];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            puncte[0] = new PointF(100, 100);
            puncte[1] = new PointF(320, 100);
            puncte[2] = new PointF(320, 320);
            puncte[3] = new PointF(100, 320);
            g.DrawPolygon(p1, puncte);

            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x, y, 40, 40);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (x < 300 && y == 80) x = x + 20;
            else if (y < 300 && x == 300) y = y + 20;
            else if (y == 300 && x > 80) x = x - 20;
            else   y = y - 20;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).